# How to fix accidentally assigned build-in function name?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I accidentally assigned build function name as variable in Jupyter notebook on google colab. Below an example of the code sample.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(5):
   sum += i
```

Not a good idea, I know but I ran this code.

Now, I have another piece of code somewhere else, like this:

```
sum([1,2,3])
```

As soon as `sum` was replaced, I have this error message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Next I figured that out and restart the runtime (option on colab to reset the kernel)

My question: Is it possible to fix the build-in function without restarting the whole runtime, but using local code updates?

I mean something like:

```
sum = <some code to assign build-in function back>
```

or like:

```
<some tool to unassign variable>('sum')
```

or similar solution.

Comment: Delete it: `del sum`

Comment: I've been there...

Comment: yes, see duplicate I just confirmed; believe it or not I was not able to find it using my keywords